# Unable to set a particular environmental variable

Tags: bash, macos

```
$ export snag='crag'
$ env | grep snag
snag=crag
$ export CORS_WHITE_LIST='please work'
$ env | grep CORS
$
```

I'm unable to set the CORS_WHITE_LIST environmental variable. I can do it with every other string except for that one...why is this? On OS X if that matters...

edit: ended up just solving this by using a new terminal session, but I'm still curious why this was happening because it frustrated me for way too long...

Comment: Do you still have the terminal where this fails open? Can you still reproduce it?

Comment: It seemed to be happening when I erroneously wrote an export: `export foo=('bar', 'baz')` (mixed up with py syntax). For some reason after running this script (which didn't produce an error) `foo` could not be reassigned in that terminal.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when the variable was previously declared as an array.

Arrays used to be exportable, but support for this was removed in the wake of ShellShock. Exporting one now has no effect.

Assigning a scalar to an array variable is perfectly valid, and expanding it will correctly show the new value, but the variable *will not stop being an array*! Instead, both operations will implicitly assign and read the 0th element.

Here's how to reproduce it:

```
$ failing=()
$ export working="Foobar" failing="Foobar"
$ env | grep Foobar
working=Foobar
```

Continuing from above, here's how you can tell them apart:

```
$ declare -p working failing
declare -x working="Foobar"
declare -ax failing=([0]="Foobar")
```

The `a` in the flags means it's an array, and therefore can't be exported. To make it exportable, you can `unset` it and try again.